# add an extra column on Tax Report of odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I need an extra column on odoo tax report. Currently there are two columns **Net** and **Tax**. I need to add a column named **Gross**. This view isn't like other qweb views and not getting it. Screenshot:

[image]

The module is **account_reports** and the file which is generating the report I think is **account_generic_tax_report**.

It would be great if anyone can suggest me what to do.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can append new column names in the list `column_header` 
 in function `get_column_names`, `addons/account_reports/models/account_generic_tax_report.py`

```
columns_header = [{}, {'name': '%s \n %s' % (_('NET'), self.format_date(dt_to, dt_from, options)), 'class': 'number', 'style': 'white-space: pre;'}, {'name': _('TAX'), 'class': 'number'} , {'name': _('New Field'), 'class': 'number'}]
```

See attached image.

[image]